# Problem 20-3 in Lee's Introduction to Smooth Manifolds

Tags: differential-geometry, solution-verification, exponential-function, lie-groups

I am trying to do Problem 20-3 in *Introduction to Smooth Manifolds* of John M. Lee and I would like to know if my answer seems correct.

> Let $G$ be a Lie group and supposer $A_1, A_2 \subset \mathfrak g$ are complementary linear subspaces of the lie algebra $\mathfrak g$ of $G$. Then the map $f:A_1 \oplus A_2 \to G: (X, Y) \mapsto \exp X \exp Y$ is a diffeomorphism from a neighborhood of $(0,0)$ into a neighborhood of $e$ in $G$.

Here is what I've done: The map $f$ can be computed as follow
$$f:A_1 \oplus A_2\mathop{\rightarrow}\limits^{\iota_1 \times \iota_2} \mathfrak g \times \mathfrak g \mathop{\rightarrow}\limits^{\exp\times\exp} G \times G \mathop{\rightarrow}\limits^{m} G,$$
with $\iota_i: A_i \to \mathfrak g$ is the inclusion. We know that $d\exp_0$ is the identity and $dm_{(e, e)}(X, Y) = X + Y$, so that $f_{*(0,0)} :T_0A_1 \oplus T_0A_2 \cong A_1 \oplus A_2 \to T_eG\cong \mathfrak g$ is given by
\begin{align}
f_{*(0,0)}(X, Y) &= dm_{(e, e)} \circ (d\exp_0\times d\exp_0)\circ ((\iota_1)_{*0}(X), (\iota_2)_{*0}(Y)) \\
&= (\iota_1)_{*0}(X) + (\iota_2)_{*0}(Y)
\end{align}
which is an isomorphism. We deduce the result from the inverse function theorem.

Comment: Hi. This looks fine to me